# Pointer to array element

Tags: c

How do I make an element of an array have the same dynamic value as another element? I need to translate something like:

```
value of array[2] = value pointed by array[4]
```

into code.

Comment: do you just copy the value of one element to another element?

Comment: So, in other words, you want the value pointed to by `array[2]` to always be the same as the value pointed to by `array[4]`, without having to update `array[2]` manually?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  If I set array[4] to 1, you want array[2] to be set to 1 also without using a second assignment statement or function call?  If so, that's just not possible.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I see to do it, is to use an array of pointers. Thus, changes to one position will affect a different position if both positions point to the same object.

Like so:

```
int* array[5];
array[2] = array[4] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*array[2] = 25;
// now, *array[4] will also be 25
```

Comment: how do I translate it to code? I have char * array; and array[2] = array[4] does not work.

Comment: There's no need for the parentheses, `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

Comment: Or if you want to have a little more fun, combine the last two lines:  `*(array[2] = array[4] = malloc(sizeof(int))) = 25`   :)

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Sure, but it obfuscates the matter here. While the second line is part of the construction of `array`, the third shows how the indirection works.